# How to set shell for npm run-scripts in Windows

Tags: windows, shell, npm

I'm running npm on Windows and would like to use & style parallel operations in run-scripts
but running in parallel in cmd is kind of messy 
in my package.json file I'd like to write-

```
scripts: { "go": "cmd1 & cmd2"}
```

but npm executes the script under cmd.exe which does not know about `;`  I could change this to
scripts: `{ "go": "bats/bat1.bat")` where bat1.bat is a cmd bat file that uses the windows style call or start commands to run commands in parallel. which works but gives me a script that only works on Windows.

It would be a lot simpler if I could get npm to run the script under a bash clone or cygwin.

I tried 
`config: { "shell": "bash"}`
but that still ran cmd.exe

Is there any way to tell npm to run-scripts using a specific shell (not cmd.exe)?

Comment: Is it [still] not possible to specify a shell in package.json?  I use npm for both windows and bash scripting and have no way of overriding the default "shell" or "script-shell" settings for a particular package.json?

Answer (score 345):

Since npm 5.1

```
npm config set script-shell "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\git\\bin\\bash.exe"
```

or *(64bit installation)*

```
npm config set script-shell "C:\\Program Files\\git\\bin\\bash.exe"
```

**Note that you need to have [git for windows installed](https://git-scm.com/download/win).**

#### You can revert it by running:

```
npm config delete script-shell
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Works on Windows 10 with Git Bash (VS Code included).

Comment: `npm config set script-shell "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"` is the answer to all my problems running parallel scripts on Windows 10 64-Bit. @DuncanSungWKim 감사합니다 for this.

Comment: Thanks , I had a problem with npm start that was working in cmd but not in bash and I ran the script you suggested and it worked!!!! After two days of googeling for an answer.... -_-
Thanks for the help

Comment: If I am already in a git bash shell and run `npm run <script` with this config, a new git bash windows is spawned running the script. This is not what I want. Is there a way to simply invoke the shell within the calling shell?

Comment: @JHH - I also had shells opening from vscode because I was using git-bash.exe instead of bash.exe.  When I fixed so vscode bash was the same as the script-shell bash, the issue was resolved.

Comment: If you're unsure about the bash.exe path, you can just do `npm config set script-shell bash` since bash.exe location is probably in `PATH`

Comment: How do you do this for cygwin?

Comment: Great advice - but be careful as this [doesn't play nice with **yarn**](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5717)

Answer (score 38):

Here's one way to do it:

1. Create a script, such as my_script.sh, in your project bin directory.
2. In your package.json file, add a line to run the script using bash. For example:

   ```
   "scripts": {
     "boogie": "bash bin/my_script.sh"
   }
   ```

Now you can run your bash script from npm by:

```
    npm run-script boogie
```

Not very elegant, but it works.

If you are developing in both Windows and Linux/Unix, then at least this approach is fairly portable to both environments.

Comment: Another option:

`"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "bash": "bash -c",
    "ls": "npm run bash ls"
}`

Answer (score 20):

Ideally, overriding the npm shell config parameter should work, but npm (at least version 1.4.14) seems in Windows to ignore the setting and use cmd.exe instead.

Use the following command in your bash or Git Bash shell to find out the shell setting:

```
$ npm config ls -l | grep shell
```

By default, the output will be:

```
shell = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe"
```

However, to override the default shell parameter, you can add (or edit) an npmrc file to the \Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc directory. Just add the following line:

```
shell = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\git\\bin\\bash.exe"
```

The path you use can be any valid path to bash.exe. Now, if you run the above "npm config ls -l | grep shell" command, you will see the following output, indicating that the shell parameter has been overriden:

```
shell = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\git\\bin\\bash.exe"
; shell = "C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe" (overridden)
```

One day, perhaps, a new version of npm will pay attention to the overridden shell parameter.

Comment: Wish this worked.  I changed the COMSPEC environment variable and it appears to be pulling from that, but I could not get it to work correctly.

Comment: This do the same job: `$ npm config set shell "C:\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\bash"`

Comment: I solved my problem following your suggestion. Now, I'm able to run scripts on npm which contain more commands separated by `;`
On Windows, in folder C:\Users\username\ I added a `.npmrc` file containing
`shell = "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"
script-shell = "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"`

Answer (score 16):

You can also use cross-platform powershell https://github.com/powershell/powershell#get-powershell for npm scripts.

To set for single project, run this from project root folder:

```
npm config set script-shell pwsh --userconfig ./.npmrc
```

To globally set for all node projects:

```
npm config set script-shell pwsh [--global]
```

Comment: I love this solution! Works well on Azure DevOps Pipelines.

Answer (score 3):

## just using CMD's way to run `.bat`!

.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "app": "cd build & browser-sync start --server --files 'index.html'",
    "bat": "start start-browser.bat",
    "starts": "start http://localhost:7777/datas/ && start http://localhost:7777/Info/"
},
```

.bat

```
start http://localhost:7777/datas/ && start http://localhost:7777/Info/
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a specifically created node_module for this purpose. I suggest using [npm-run-all](https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all/), but [others](https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all/issues/10) exists, such as [parallelshell](https://github.com/keithamus/parallelshell).

Parallelshell example is below for drop-in-replacement for your question.

```
"scripts": {
    "parallelexample1": "parallelshell \"echo 1\" \"echo 2\" \"echo 3\""
},
```

following command:

```
npm run parallelexample1
```

works both on windows and unix(Linux/MacOS).

Interestingly npm-run-all does not support shell commands; therefore we need to put all shell commands to separate scripts like below.

```
"scripts": {
   "parallelexample2": "npm-run-all echo*",
    "echo1": "echo 1",
    "echo2": "echo 2",
    "echo3": "echo 3"
},
```

Following command:

```
npm run parallelexample2
```

works both on windows and unix(Linux/MacOS).

Comment: thanks for the tip for npm-run-all, I tried the `--parallel` option also

Comment: as you can see, on windows machine, the scripts needs to be escaped using [\" command \"] format

Answer (score 1):

In my case I just needed to run `npm start` from inside Bash. I run `cmd` then I open bash by running `"c:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe"`. Under bash shell I then was able to call `npm build` and `npm start` succesfully.

You may already have bash if you are using Git. If not, you can [install](https://git-scm.com/download/win) it.

Hope this may save someone's time.

Comment: Doesn't work with all scripts that do work on linux, like for example having `PORT=8000`