# How can I add a timestamp into a script in package.json?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

It may not be possible (because this is JSON not JavaScript). I'm just trying to think of the simplest way to insert a datestamp in a string from an npm command without adding the overhead of another task runner etc:

```
"scripts": {
    "deploy" : "git add -A; git commit -m \"automated deployment {DateStamp}\"; git push deployment browse --force;"
},
```

And no need to chide me for using `--force` ;)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

NPM scripts are just bash scripts. Use bash features to add datestamp to some commit message.

Example:

```
  "scripts": {
    "deploy" : "git add -A; timestamp=$(date \"+%s\") && git commit -m \"automated deployment $timestamp\"; git push deployment browse --force;"
  },
```

Comment: Great.. I [used `%c` instead of `%s`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-conversion-specifiers.html#Date-conversion-specifiers) to make it more readable.. but you did give me exactly what I asked for ;)

Comment: Is there a platform independent way to achieve the same result on Windows/Linux?

Comment: Another example using a file-friendly datetime: `"table-to-csv": "TODAY=$(date \"+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S\"); node script.js --file exported-at-$TODAY.csv"`

Comment: To use same script on windows, see this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25614832/1012616

Answer (score 0):

**Result: 1685441258**

You can pass the date like this:

```
{
    "name": "javascript",
    "config" : { "filename" : "test2" },
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "My javascript",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "remotion render HelloWorld out/$(date \"+%s\").mp4",
    }
}
```

Output:
[image]

**For result: 2023-05-31_13-15-30**

To get the result in YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-ss: ie. 2023-05-31_13-15-30, you can do this:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "remotion render src/index.tsx Story results/$(date \"+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S\").mp4",
}
```

[image]
[image]