# How to pass current datetime in npm script for git commit message in Windows and cross platform?

Tags: windows, git, terminal, cross-platform, npm-scripts

I am working in Windows 10 and trying to use npm script for git commit with message that includes date and time of the commit:

```
"deploy": "cd dist && git add . && git commit -m \"Release at $(date)\" && git push"
```

Resulting git commit message is

> Release at $(date)

instead of

> Release at 03/06/2019 11:43:57

that I get when running in terminal the same command:

```
git commit -m "Release at $(date)"
```

What is a cross platform solution ?

Can you explain what causes different results ?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33151617/how-can-i-add-a-timestamp-into-a-script-in-package-json) will help. It's a bash solution. You can run bash on windows

Comment: I tried: "deploy": "cd dist && git add -A; timestamp=$(date \"+%s\") && git commit -m \"Release at $timestamp\" && git push", but I  am getting "error: unknown switch `;'

Comment: You should be using a `bash shell`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203723/how-do-i-write-a-batch-file-which-opens-the-gitbash-shell-and-runs-a-command-in) out. I think `git-bash`, the one you got when you installed git can run bash scripts

Answer (score 8):

*Cross-platform* compatibility cannot be realized by utilizing the shell command [`date`](https://ss64.com/bash/date.html) that is available on  **nix* platforms. This is because the Windows/*cmd.exe* [`DATE`](https://ss64.com/nt/date.html) command behaves differently. The differences are:

- The *nix `date` command prints the date/time.
- The Windows/*cmd.exe* `DATE` command prompts the user to set the system date/time.

Also [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html), i.e. the `$(...)` part is a bash feature found on most *nix shells - it will fail via Windows *cmd.exe*.

For a *cross-platform* solution (i.e. one that runs successfully on Windows, Linux, and macOS...), consider the following approach:

- Utilize a nodejs script to *shell-out* your `cd` and `git` commands using the built-in [`execSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options).
- Obtain the date using the [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) package, or alternatively using the JavaScript [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632346/how-to-format-a-date-in-mm-dd-yyyy-hhmmss-format-in-javascript#answer-10632399) instead.
- Invoke the nodejs script from the `scripts` section of your *package.json*

---

### Solution:

There are a couple of different ways to approach this as described in the following two sub-sections titled:

- Using an external nodejs (.js) file
- Inlining your JavaScript in *package.json*.

***Note:** both approaches effectively yield the same desired result.*

#### Using an external nodejs (.js) file

1. The following utilizes `moment` for obtaining the date. To install that run the following command in your project directory:

   ```
   npm i -D moment
   ```
2. Create a nodejs script as follows, let's name the file *deploy.js* and save it in the root of your project directory, i.e. in the same directory where *package.json* currently resides::

   **deploy.js**

   ```js
   const moment = require('moment');
   const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;

   const dateTime = moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss');

   execSync(`cd dist && git add . && git commit -m \"Release at ${dateTime}\" && git push`, { stdio: [0, 1, 2]} );
   ```
3. In the `scripts` section of your *package.json* replace your current `deploy` script with the following:

   **package.json**

   ```json
   "scripts": {
     "deploy": "node deploy"
   }
   ```
4. Invoke the npm `deploy` script as per normal by running the following via your CLI:

   ```
   npm run deploy
   ```

**Explanation:**

- In *deploy.js* we require the `moment` package and the nodejs built-in `execSync()`.
- To obtain the current date/time we invoke `moment()` and call its [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) method to match your given formatting, i.e. `MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss`.
- We then *shell-out* your `cd` and `git`commands using `execSync`. A reference to the date/time is provided in  the `git` message part using [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), i.e.`${dateTime}`
- The [`options.stdio`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio) option configures the pipes between the parent and child process - `[0, 1, 2]` effectively inherit's `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`.

#### Inlining your JavaScript in package.json.

Alternatively, you can inline your nodejs/JavaScript code in the `scripts` section of your *package.json*.

1. In the scripts section of your *package.json* replace your current `deploy` script with the following instead:

   **package.json**

   ```json
   "scripts": {
     "deploy": "node -e \"const dateTime = require('moment')().format('MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss'); require('child_process').execSync(`cd dist && git add . && git commit -m \"Release at ${dateTime}\" && git push`, { stdio: [0, 1, 2]} );\""
   }
   ```

**Explanation:**

- This is effectively the same as the aforementioned solution that utilized a separate `.js` file (albeit slightly refactored). The use of a separate nodejs script/file is now redundant.
- The nodejs command line option [`-e`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_e_eval_script) is utilized to evaluate the inline JavaScript.