# npm scripts: read .env file

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

I have a simple requirement: In my npm scripts package.json file I have the line:

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "example": "some-lib --argument --domain \"https://tld.com\""
    }
}
```

Now I want the "domain" to be factored out.

First try is to use `$npm_package_config`, which works:

```json
{
    "config": {
        "domain": "https://tld.com"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "example": "some-lib --argument --domain \"$npm_package_config_domain\""
    }
}
```

But I want the domain loaded from an local .env file.

I did not find any solution out there to read the contents of an env file inside npm scripts on the command line.

Can somebody give me a hint to a possible solution for this problem?

Comment: Have you seen dotenv-cli? https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-cli

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A much easier solution is to just use bash to parse the env file in-line and extract the variable you want:

Assuming your `.env` file looks like:

```
DOMAIN=https://tld.com
```

```
"scripts": {
  "example": "some-lib --argument --domain $(grep DOMAIN .env | cut -d '=' -f2)"
}
```

Comment: However, not so cool when cross-platform is a requirement as this fails in non-bash shells -  notably windows cmd.exe

Comment: This is quite old yet still useful to me. Just wondering if there are any enhancements to this? Also is it possible to supply a default value for the env var, just in case it’s missing in the env file or the file doesn’t exist. I know I can do ${DOMAIN:-mydomain} but what is the syntax in this use case?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20909045/1181570) has some enhancements, such as ignoring lines beginning with #, handling values with spaces in them, and loading an entire .env file instead of just one variable

Comment: `cut: invalid field value ')'` error in Windows Git Bash.

Answer (score 24):

**Short answer:** There's no terse way to achieve this that works cross-platform, as per your second example which references the `$npm_package_config` variable.

For a cross-platform solution, i.e. one that works successfully on both **nix* and Windows platforms - whereby the default shell utilized by npm scripts is either `sh` or `cmd` respectively, you'll need to execute your command (i.e. the one which is currently defined in your npm-script) via a nodejs helper script. Essentially, your nodejs script will need to:

- Utilize the [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) package to load the `.env` file.
- Execute the command using the nodejs built-in module; [`child_process.exec()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) or [`child_process.execSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options).

The nodejs helper script can then be invoked via your npm-script.

The following describes how to achieve a solution that runs cross-platform.

---

### Solution

#### 1. The .env file

Firstly, lets assume we have a *.env* file residing in the root of our project directory. The `.env` file contains the following entry:

```
DOMAIN=https://tld.com
```

#### 2. Install

The following nodejs script utilizes the [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) package to load the environment variable(s) from the *.env* file. We'll need to install it. To do this `cd` to your project directory and run the following command:

```
npm i -D dotenv
```

#### 3. The Node.js script (*some-lib-cmd.js*)

Next create a nodejs script as follows. Let's name the file ***some-lib-cmd.js*** and save it in the root of the project directory:

```js
// Requirements...
require('dotenv').config();
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
const path = require("path");

/**
 * Creates a path to an executable in the node_modules/.bin directory. Each
 * path segment is joined with the appropriate platform-specific separator as
 * a delimiter.
 * @param {String} cmd The name of the executable.
 * @returns {String} The path to the executable.
 */
function getBinFile(cmd) {
  return path.join('node_modules', '.bin', cmd);
}

// Execute the command...
execSync(`${getBinFile('some-lib')} --argument --domain ${process.env.DOMAIN}`, { stdio: [0, 1, 2] });
```

**Notes:**

- If your *.env* file does not reside in the root of our project directory along with *some-lib-cmd.js*, then you can utilize *dotenv's* [`path`](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#path) option to define a custom path to the location of your `.env` file instead. For example:

  ```js
  require('dotenv').config({ path: 'path/to/another/folder/' })
  ```
- To reference the `DOMAIN` variable from within the nodejs script we utilize [`process.env`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env), i.e. `process.env.DOMAIN`.

#### 4. package.json

In the `scripts` section of your *package.json* define the following script:

```json
"scripts": {
  "example": "node some-lib-cmd"
}
```

**Note:** If you have chosen to save *some-lib-cmd.js* elsewhere, i.e. not in the in the root of your project directory, then redefine the path in your `example` script as necessary. For instance:

```json
"scripts": {
  "example": "node path/to/some/folder/some-lib-cmd"
}
```

Comment: Thanks RobC for your detailled help. I just published a package for this problem, have a look at https://github.com/vielhuber/from-env

Comment: @DavidVielhuber https://github.com/toddbluhm/env-cmd/ has been doing this for awhile?

Comment: @DavidVielhuber - You say _"can you give an example how ..."_ Is this a question for me or Akkuma ? b.t.w Briefly looking at 'env-cmd' it doesn't seem to provide a bulltin solution  to use a variable inside your npm script  as Akkuma suggests.

Comment: Sorry, wrong thread. @Akkuma can you give an example how env-cmd uses environment variables inside a npm script? I don't think thats possible.

Comment: `"scripts": { "webhooks:dev-rg": "env-cmd --use-shell 'ts-node src/MyUtils/webhooks_register.ts https://${DEV_RESOURCEGROUP}.azurewebsites.net'"...`

Comment: any update since https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v20.x/docs/api/cli.html#--env-fileconfig ?

Answer (score 21):

Let's say you have a `.env` file like this:

```
DOMAIN="https://tld.com"
```

Then, you can use [`source`](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Source_command) in your command, like so:

```
{
    // ...
    "scripts": {
        "example": "source .env && some-lib --argument --domain $DOMAIN"
    }
}
```

This won't work in Windows by default, but if you have Git Bash installed, then you can configure npm to use it to run commands with e.g. (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23243353/how-to-set-shell-for-npm-run-scripts-in-windows)):

```
npm config set script-shell "C:\\Program Files\\git\\bin\\bash.exe"
```

Comment: I had to specify the path to the env file as `./.env` or else I got a **file not found** error. As a side note, if you need to persist these variables into the node process subshell you can add `set -a &&` before the `source` command to automatically export all the vars it contains.

Comment: Please mind that if you run this setup as part of an npm script, you have to specify path to `.env` file relative to `package.json`, not to the file in which your script is written

Comment: Using `source` in a npm script returns `sh: 1: source: not found`. I'm on Ubuntu.

Comment: I believe `source` can be replaced by simply `.`. @Fred, try this :-)

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I'll try. Using `env-cmd` npm package right now and it works fine :-)

Comment: Is there a reason why this is being up-voted when it isn't cross platform? Isn't that the point of using node? Should support Windows and Linux

Answer (score 7):

There is a library that does exactly what you want to follow 12factor app best practices: the dotenv package from npmjs.org

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

FTA:

```
$ node -r dotenv/config your_script.js dotenv_config_path=/custom/path/to/your/env/vars
```

Comment: Is this still required, even after https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v20.x/docs/api/cli.html#--env-fileconfig ?

Answer (score 3):

Surprised no one mentioned the 'ol tried and true DirEnv to auto setup environment for your current working directory. That way env is private to your local machine and available to all your scripts including inside the code base. It comes in handy for things that won't look at a .env file by default.

I use this all over my machine not just in development
projects.

Def worth checking out!
[Direnv](https://direnv.net/)

Comment: Yeah this is cool but can't expect other to have it too.

Comment: If others are installing your software, you can cause put your dependencies in package.json and then others will have the dotenv lib too....