# How can I use SECRET_ENV in npm scripts inside of package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables, secret-key

I have a secret key called `API_KEY` that I want to access inside of `package.json`'s `scripts`.

## package.json

```
{
   "scripts": {
      "start": "web-ext run --api-key=API_KEY"
   }
}
```

My `.env` file contains `API_KEY`:

```
API_KEY=abc123
```

How can I access the value of `API_KEY` inside `package.json`'s `scripts` while still keeping it a secret because I need to push `package.json` publicly?

Currently, I do the following which works but not cross-platform:

## package.json

```
{
   "scripts": {
      "start": "web-ext run --api-key=$API_KEY"
   }
}
```

And when running `start` script I do it like:

```
API_KEY=abc123 npm start
```

This works thanks to Bash Programming Language but it doesn't work on Windows. I need to replace `$API_KEY` in `start` script with `%API_KEY%`. But I want it to be cross-platform. Is there any other way?

Comment: Why not just simply create a directory called config with a js file named config.js and do a module export of that api key? Than copy that file and name it config.js.example that would be empty with a file exclusion in .gitignore?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set environment variables from within package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112510/how-to-set-environment-variables-from-within-package-json)

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ imo it's not a duplicate as i want to keep the environment variables value private. there is an answer containing `env-cmd` which might've worked for my case but it can't as i want to use the variable as an argument to `--api-key` so can't do that according to https://github.com/toddbluhm/env-cmd-examples/issues/3#issuecomment-526069343

Comment: "*when running `start` script I do it like `API_KEY=abc123 npm start`*" - why use environment variables at all when you have a cli parameter for that? Just drop the `--api-key=API_KEY` from the package.json - no issues with cross-platform compatibility - and call it like `npm start --api-key=abc123`.

Comment: @Bergi I still need to remember the argument `--api-key` & `--api-secret`. So rather than that, I find my own solution to be good suggested in the question. Only thing to make it work on Windows, is to change `$API_KEY` to `%API_KEY%`. When I posted the question, I thought a simpler solution exists but unfortunately it doesn't :(

Answer (score 2):

The only other viable answer to this I found so far is a bit hacky:

```
{
   "scripts": {
      "start": "web-ext run --api-key=$(grep API_KEY .env | cut -d '=' -f2)"
   }
}
```

[https://stackoverflow.com/a/58038814/1822977]

Answer (score 1):

### For cross platform

1) You can use 'npm [env-cmd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd)' as a  `devDependencies`.

> Setting the environment from a file

#### Usage

**Environment file `./.env`**

```
# This is a comment
API_KEY=abc123
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd web-ext run"
  }
}
```

---

2) You can use 'npm [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env)' as a  `devDependencies`.

> Run scripts that set and use environment variables across platforms

**Usage**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env API_KEY=abc123 web-ext run"
  }
}
```

---

### For Windows only

You can try something like this:

```
cmd /C "set API_KEY=abc123 && npm start"
```

As [Viper_Sb says here](https://superuser.com/a/223126):

> /C exits the new cmd right away after running, if you produce output with the new one it will still be visible in the parent window.
>
> You can opt to use /K in which case the new cmd window stays open at the end of the run.

Comment: Can't use `env-cmd` as I want to pass it as an argument to `--api-key`. Can't use `cross-env` as I need to keep the value `abc123` private. The third one is only Windows :(

Comment: `env-cmd` doesn't work for me as pointed on this issue → https://github.com/toddbluhm/env-cmd-examples/issues/3#issuecomment-526069343 which is exactly what i want to do

Answer (score 0):

## Cross-Plattform: Using dotenv-cli & cross-var

> Disclaimer: Only tested with Windows 11 (PowerShell 7 and CMD) so far.

> Requires [dotenv-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-cli) and [cross-var](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-var) (or a fork like [x-var](https://www.npmjs.com/package/x-var))

dotenv-cli: Makes the values from `.env` accessible inside the scripts-section.

cross-var: Makes it usable cross-plattform with `$API_KEY` when between  `\" \"` like `\"$API_KEY\"`.

### .env

```
API_KEY='sdf8879123sdfi'
API_ENDPOINT='https://api.example.com'
```

### packages.json

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "check-env": "dotenv -- cross-var echo \"$API_ENDPOINT\"",
    "start-v1": "dotenv -- cross-var YOUR-CUSTOM-START-COMMAND --api=\"$API_ENDPOINT\" --key=\"$API_KEY\""
    "start-v2": "dotenv -- cross-var \" YOUR-CUSTOM-START-COMMAND --api=$API_ENDPOINT --api-key=$API_KEY \""

 }
  "devDependencies": {
    "cross-var": "^1.1.0",
    "dotenv-cli": "^7.0.0",
  }
}
```

#### Syntax-Explanation

`dotenv --`: The `--` belongs to dotenv-cli, and it's used as a separator. It's helpful to specify which flags belong to `dotenv` like `dotenv -e .env.local -- [...]` and which belong to the rest.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply require "dotenv" lib, and access var from process.env.{SOME_KEY}

Comment: No, `dotenv` doesn't work that way AFAICT. i need to access it in `package.json` > `scripts` & not a `*.js` file. `dotenv` needs to be loaded first and then used inside `*.js` file :)