# Using .env file syntax error is showing in Values: nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to implement the nodemailer for contacts form. I have gone through many resources and I got the below code.
**server.js**

```
// require('dotenv').config();
require('dotenv').config({ path: require('./.env') });
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const cors = require("cors");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/", router);
app.listen(5000, () => console.log("Server Running"));

const contactEmail = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: process.env.USERNAME,
    pass: process.env.PASSWORD,
  },
});

contactEmail.verify((error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log("Ready to Send");
  }
});

router.post("/contact", (req, res) => {
  const name = req.body.name;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const phonenumber= req.body.phonenumber;
  const address= req.body.address;
  const EmailSubject= req.body.EmailSubject;
  const message = req.body.message; 
  const mail = {
    from: name,
    to: process.env.SEND_TO_EMAIL,
    // subject: "Email from Fans",
    subject: 'Email From Fans: ' + EmailSubject,
    html: `<p>Name: ${name}</p><p>Email: ${email}</p><p>Contact No: ${phonenumber}</p><p>Address: ${address}</p><p>Message: ${message}</p>`,
  };
  contactEmail.sendMail(mail, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      res.json({ status: "ERROR" });
    } else {
      res.json({ status: "Thanks for your time. Your message has been sent successfully!" });
    }
  });
});
```

In this file, it's clearly mentioned that I am using the dotenv for the environment to take the value from the .env file.
below is my **.env** file

```
USERNAME = example@gmail.com
PASSWORD = **********
SEND_TO_EMAIL = example2@gmail.com
API_HOST = http://localhost:5000/contact
```

When I am running command **node server**
then I am getting below error.

```
PS E:\project> node server
E:\project\.env:1
USERNAME = example@gmail.com
                  ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
```

I don't understand what mistakes I have done. Is there any rule to run or access the .env file?
I followed the two discussion

1. [Cant access variables from .env file in node.js application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68126979/cant-access-variables-from-env-file-in-node-js-application)
2. [Node.js Everywhere with Environment Variables!](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/making-your-node-js-work-everywhere-with-environment-variables-2da8cdf6e786)
   But still no luck!

Comment: `require('dotenv').config({ path: require('./.env') });`. I don't think you've to require the `path` in the configuration but give a string as path `require('dotenv').config({ path: './.env' });`

Comment: @SrinathKamath same error Server Running Error: Missing credentials for "PLAIN"

Comment: Are you able to get the env variables in the console? try to print the variables in the console.

Comment: @SrinathKamath It's not getting print `undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined`

Comment: There you go, you have the answer! So just try removing the path from config. 
By default `dotenv` tries to find a `.env` in the same folder from where the function was called. otherwise provide a path like so `config( { path : 'path/to/your/env' } )`

Comment: @SrinathKamath It's working now after many attempts.:), thanks!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235673/discussion-between-srinath-kamath-and-kwall).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try :

```
USERNAME='example@gmailcom'
```

There should not be space between assignments.

Comment: Now I am getting a new error `node server
Server Running
Error: Missing credentials for "PLAIN"`

Comment: You must be using some actual email address and password. if using gmail address, it's not going to allow you directly. you may need to enable from Google oauth credentials.

Comment: You may find more details on this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48854066/missing-credentials-for-plain-nodemailer

Comment: OK, but whenever I put the correct credential instead of process.env.USERNAME then It's working fine.

Comment: var env = require('node-env-file');

env(__dirname + '/.env');

can you give a try on 'node-env-file' it's working for me.

Comment: Should I need to install node-env-file or packages?

Comment: yes, you need to install.

Answer (score 1):

As Deepak Jha pointed out, there should be no spaces between the assignments:

```
USERNAME='SOME_VALUE'
```

For the error `Missing credentials for "PLAIN"` that's an authentication error from Gmail. Here is a thread about that: [Missing credentials for “PLAIN” nodemailer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48854066/missing-credentials-for-plain-nodemailer).

Answer (score 0):

Simple but please try USERNAME = "example@gmailcom". The error is pointing the @ character. And add the missing dot ;)

Comment: I am getting same error node server Server Running Error: Missing credentials for "PLAIN"

Comment: Well, that's another error, an auth error.

Comment: Didn't get you. could you explain more?

Comment: Of course, sorry. That error is not a problem with your code, now your code is ok and you have to check your credentials and the authentication with Gmail as Andres Diaz mentioned