# npm start does not work for ract template project

Tags: reactjs, npm

Running npm start after npm init does not work due to reported missing react-script library.

It is on my Windows 10 machine; I tried uninstalling and reinstalling node but it did not help.

I can only run my project by typing

```
>node .\node_modules\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js start
```

otherwise  if I run:

```
>npm start
```

I can see errors pasted below.

reactapptest@0.1.0 start C:(...)\reactapptest
react-scripts start
npm ERR! file bash
npm ERR! path bash
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn bash
npm ERR! reactapptest@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! spawn bash ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the reactapptest@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

It looks like something is wrong with my path but I am not sure and I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: Try upgrading npm with `npm install -g npm@latest` to see if it is NPM trying to spawn bash "on its own" or if that is invoked via-via by `react-scripts`.

Comment: I tried; it is still the same error popping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific error you are getting points out that `bash` is not available. Now `bash` is a shell for Unix and Unix-like environments, it is not typically installed on Windows by default. (Though it is available for Windows as well through MinGW.)

You are working on Windows, you should not *need* bash with `react-scripts`. Try upgrading npm with `npm install -g npm@latest` to see if this is caused by an old and broken version of npm on your system.

EDIT: Also, you may have previously configured `npm` to use `bash`. See: [how to set shell for npm run-scripts in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23243353/how-to-set-shell-for-npm-run-scripts-in-windows) and note that you are pretty much trying to do the opposite, so if you have custom configuration you might want to try removing it (also explained in the linked accepted answer).

Comment: >npm config delete script-shell solved the problem; thank you