# How can I make npm projects with Bash shell commands work on Windows?

Tags: shell, powershell, npm, cmd, command-line

I have some NPM scripts on a project i recently took over that go like this:

```
{
    "package": "yarn package-common && mv './dist/APP® TV.wgt' ''./package/$(yarn -s filename)''",
    "package-common": "tizen package -t wgt -s APP -- ./dist && rimraf package && mkdir package",
    "filename": "cross-env-shell echo APP_${npm_package_version}.wgt",
}
```

This project was written by someone on a MAC. How can i translate the following part into a functioning Powershell / cmd command? I havent found anything anywhere about this. It runs the command and the echoed value gets appended to the string it got called from.

```
''./package/$(yarn -s filename)''
```

Or even better, is there a way besides [this](https://github.com/milewski/cross-os) package to do it cross-platform?

Currently the message that gets output in powershell when running yarn package is:

```
'' was unexpected at this time.
```

Comment: As an aside: The error message comes from `cmd.exe`, which npm uses by default on Windows.

Comment: If cross-platform is a requirement I suggest rewriting it all in a _node.js_ script and _shell-out_ the necessary commands using [`execSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options) (or [`exec`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) if you want asynchronous). You can then invoke the _node.js_ script via an npm-script, i,e. `"package": "node somescript.js"`

Comment: Or evaluate (i.e. `node -e ...`) the _node.js_ script inline from your npm script. E.g.  `"package": "yarn package-common && node -e \"var sh = require('child_process').execSync; var fn = sh('yarn -s filename', {encoding: 'utf8'}); sh('mv ./dist/APP®TV.wgt ./package/' + fn);\"",` This will run cross-platform, however the most problematic part in your script is the combination of registered symbol plus space char in the path `./dist/APP® TV.wgt`. It's an encoding nightmare with _cmd.exe_. I suggest you change it (if you can) to e.g. `./dist/APP®TV.wgt ` as per the aforementioned npm script.

Comment: For running in a Windows only environment using the npm default _cmd.exe_ you may want to consider changing your `package` script to: `"package": "yarn package-common && FOR /F %f IN ('yarn -s filename') DO mv ./dist/\"APP®TV.wgt\" ./package/%~f",` -  this also will entail changing the `./dist/APP® TV.wgt` path to `./dist/APP®TV.wgt`, i.e. omitting the combination of registered symbol plus space character to negate the encoding nightmare.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your basic choices for **going *cross-platform* without *platform-specific* scripts** are:

- **Use Bash also on Windows**:

  - Run your npm scripts from Bash **via [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)** and **use the existing Bash commands** typically contained in `package.json` files, such as in your case.
  - Alternatively, with **[Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win)** installed, configure npm to use `bash.exe` as the shell for invoking commands - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46006249/45375) [npm v5.1+].
- **Install [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/powershell/powershell) on all your platforms** (including Windows), and **define the commands as PowerShell commands** (see below) [npm v5.1+].

Note the npm version version requirement (version 5.1 or higher) where noted, due to the configuration option to use a specific shell (`script-shell`) not being available in earlier versions. Run `npm -v` to get the installed version, and 
`npm install -g npm` to update, if possible.

---

#### Using npm with PowerShell (Core) on all platforms [npm v5.1+]:

- [Install](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/tree/master/docs/learning-powershell#installing-powershell) PowerShell Core.
- Then configure npm to use PowerShell (Core) as the shell (requires npm version 5.1 or higher):

  - For *all* your projects (current user), or *globally* (all users):

    ```bash
    npm config set script-shell pwsh [--global]
    ```
  - For a *given project* only (from that project's root directory):

    ```bash
    npm config set script-shell pwsh --location project

    # Equivalent in older npm versions:
    npm config set script-shell pwsh --userconfig ./.npmrc
    ```
- Finally, in your projects' `package.json`'s `scripts` key, define the commands as PowerShell commands.

In the case at hand:

For instance, translate this Bash command:

```bash
yarn package-common && mv './dist/APP® TV.wgt' "./package/$(yarn -s filename)"
```

<sup>Note: I've replaced `''` with `"`, because the latter make more sense; as originally written, the `''` are effectively *discarded* by Bash, and the result of command substitution `$(yarn -s filename)` could break the command if it contained whitespace.</sup>

to this PowerShell command (v7+):

```bash
yarn package-common && mi './dist/APP® TV.wgt' "./package/$(yarn -s filename)"
```

Note:

- `mi` is a built-in alias for PowerShell's [`Move-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/move-item) cmdlet.
- While it makes sense to call your scripts *from PowerShell* also, that's not a requirement - calling from `cmd.exe` or a batch file will work too.
- To get started with PowerShell (Core), see [Learning PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/tree/master/docs/learning-powershell); also, http://hyperpolyglot.org/shell juxtaposes the syntax of POSIX-like shells such as Bash with that of `cmd.exe` and PowerShell in concise, tabular form.

Comment: The "modern" npm syntax for setting a config in the current project is `npm config set script-shell pwsh --location project`. This creates a local .npmrc file.

Comment: Thanks, @ChristianDavén - I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to shamelessly promote my solution to this problem. I was facing the same issues and decided to write a little tool to fix this once and for all. The result is a small Bash interpreter that is able to work on all platforms where NodeJS can run, including Windows. As a nice bonus, it supports running tasks in parallel too.

In short, you can replace `npm run x` with `bake x` and it will work. All scripts specified after the command will run in parallel, and if you install `@samvv/bake` as a dependency you'll be able to use it in your npm scripts as well, like so:

```
{
  "scripts": {
     "watch:compile-tests": "tsc -w",
     "watch:tests": "ava --watch",
     "test": "ava",
     "lint": "tsc --noEmit",
     "prepare": "npm run lint && webpack --mode production",
     "serve": "webpack serve --mode development",
     "lint-while-testing": "bake lint test"
  }
}
```

You can find the source code [here](https://github.com/samvv/BakeJS) and you'll be able to install the package using `npm install -g @samvv/bake`. See [this Medium post](https://samvv.medium.com/supercharge-your-javascript-build-scripts-with-bake-282279b40c7a) for more information on how it works and how to use it.

I really hope this is useful to someone!