# Nuxt access git version or hash at build time and use in page

Tags: git, vue.js, github, nuxt.js, netlify

I have a Nuxt/Vue app that I am deploying through Netlify.  I'm trying to inject the git version number and hash into the `body` of the page.  I'm assuming there is a pretty straightforward way to do this (but I don't know what it is!).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In package.json, you can pass the commit hash before call Nuxt:

```
"scripts": {
  "dev": "NUXT_ENV_CURRENT_GIT_SHA=`git rev-parse --short HEAD` nuxt",
  ...
},
```

Then, you can recover the value anywhere with `process.env.NUXT_ENV_CURRENT_GIT_SHA`.

Comment: Does not work for me (Git Bash on Windows): `'NUXT_ENV_CURRENT_GIT_SHA' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: I suppose the problem is, that you [need to explicitly set the shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23243353/how-to-set-shell-for-npm-run-scripts-in-windows) to bash for npm on Windows, it does not suffice, calling it from git-bash. Albeit I have not tested it, kind of allergic to Windows. :)

Answer (score 1):

In `nuxt.config.js` I'm setting an `env` (`COMMIT_REF` is an always-defined `env` in Netlify) but it is the long hash and I would be grateful if anyone had a solution for the short hash.

```
env: {
    COMMIT_REF: process.env.COMMIT_REF || 'COMMIT_REF'
}
```

Comment: I need help how to use this env in our nuxt app.

Comment: @Goutham what kind of help?

Comment: @Goutham You can access env in your app since Nuxt tells Webpack to inject the env variables into your application, see https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-env/