# git bash does not recognize "environment path" when using package.json scripts

Tags: bash, npm, visual-studio-code, scripting, git-bash

I am trying to `yarn start` with git bash
`"start": "node scripts/start.js",`
It always works when using PowerShell or CMD.
But it does not work with git bash.

But when I tried to `node scripts/start.js` instead `yarn start` with bash it works!

I tested git bash
`yarn -v, node -v, npm -v,`
every command works well.

But not work with scripts...

This is the error message

```
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

And i tried to
`"startStart": "yarn start",`
And this time bash gives me this error message

```
'yarn ' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

I checked my env `PATH` but all is fine.

---  ENV
VS_CODE
OS : window 10
node : 13.5
npm : 6.13.4

I installed git-bash with git
And all install config is default-standard

---

## Add

I think Git-Bash can find the path when it is alone
I think we should focus on that it can't find path only when it try to trigger `package.json` scripts

About `.profile` I didn't know what it is and I never created it.
If it is not default - exist I don't have it.

Comment: when you run `echo $PATH` do you see `<path_to_NODE>`

Comment: If you `cd` to your project directory and run the following command via git bash: `npm run env | grep ^PATH=` and similarly using [`yarn-run-env`](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/run/#toc-yarn-run-env) command, i.e. `yarn run env | grep ^PATH=` - what do they it return ?

Comment: Could you please do let us know if you imported your DOT profile in your script?

Comment: @madhu sudhan yes i can see like this ```...:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/cmd:/c/Users/colto....```

Comment: Does `ls -l /c/Program Files/nodejs/node` show that the x-bit is set?

Comment: @RobC i can see paths.....  ```PATH=/c/Program Files/nodejs/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/c/Users/colto/Desktop/projects/jd-booking-client/node_modules/.bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/colto/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/NAT Service:/c/ProgramData/Boxstarter:/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Intel/Shared Libraries/redist/intel64/compi...```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13  I just knew that what is .profile and i never created it. i tried to figure out file is exist or not ... it dose not exist i think -

Comment: @user1934428 I do not know what you mean but ...  ```/c/Program Files/nodejs``` in here i try to command ```ls -l``` and i got   ```total 28143
-rw-r--r-- 1 colto 197610     2953 Dec 16 17:03 install_tools.bat  
-rwxr-xr-x 1 colto 197610 28787352 Dec 17 06:55 node.exe  
-rw-r--r-- 1 colto 197610     8997 Oct 10 06:01 node_etw_provider.man  
drwxr-xr-x 1 colto 197610        0 Dec 30 18:08 node_modules  
-rw-r--r-- 1 colto 197610      702 Oct 10 06:01 nodevars.bat  
-rwxr-xr-x 1 colto 197610      930 Dec 13 06:01 npm  
-rw-r--r-- 1 colto 197610      483 Oct 10 06:01 npm.cmd```

Comment: If you invoke _node_ by its full path, `"/c/Program Files/nodejs/node.exe"` (don't forget the quotes), does it work then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

without to relate to windows specific, npm executes [`scripts`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) commands (specified in `package.json`) under the default shell, but it does not perform a login to the shell.

for instance, a [bash login](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) (`bash --login`) in order to use your custom system environment variable.

you can change this by using [`.npmrc`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc) file and set the `script-shell`. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46006249) for the solution.

i hope this is what you suffer from :)

Comment: Yes it is what i suffer from  :) TY   - now it works