# unable to create a new project with create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app

I've just finished installing create-react-app successfully.
But, when I create a new project like below command, error happens.
Could you please give me a recommandation?

system env.:
- aws lightsail 1vcpu, 0.5G ram / ubuntu 18.04
- nodejs version : 13.9.0
- npm version : 6.13.7
- create-react-app version : 3.4.0

~$ npm create-react-app my-app

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall /home/ubuntu/my-app/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
>   node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json

Done.

Comment: try `npx create-react-app appname`

Comment: Can you try these [steps to create a react project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62122386/2873538)?

Answer (score 2):

### Switch to Yarn

It was a [raised](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11933) issue on github a couple of years back..
it was solved after switching to yarn.
These commands could not solve the issue.

```
npm cache clean --force
create-react-app my-apps
```

Switching to Yarn worked!

```
npm install -g yarn
yarn global add create-react-app
create-react-app my-app
```

See if this helps!

Comment: Aditya issue is not with `yarn` or any other package installer. It is related to `create-react-app` command itself.

Comment: You are right. But if you could go through the discussions  under the closed issue
 https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11933, the conclusion was switching to yarn to get it work. This a work around. If this is fixed by now in the cra , suggest an edit to this answer. Thanks

Comment: Even in Linux, using `yarn`, a wrong bash path is assumed as `core-js` tries to run script inside `SHELL`, so your alternative solution is not a universal solution, ultimately one has to find how to deal with `facebook/create-react-app` mess!

Answer (score 2):

This error is due to the fact that a dependant module named `core-js` is trying to run a post-install script. This post-install script spawns a child process and runs a shell script there. For some reason Node sets/assumes a wrong bash path by default. I had to manually change the path by running the following command.

```
npm config set script-shell $(which sh)
```

**Note**: For Windows you might have to setup your own `bash.exe` by installing something like git-bash and then you could assign the path similarly.

Comment: thank you this worked for me, I also found this question related on how to set it, if it helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46006249/10945921

Answer (score 0):

Try this: npm cache clean --force