# i want to create react app but i can't. Any help will be appreciated

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS D:\Amazon> npx create-react-app amazon-clone

Creating a new React app in D:\Amazon\amazon-clone.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

added 1919 packages, and audited 1920 packages in 3m

147 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

10 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:
npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.

Comment: is there any error? if not there should be a directory amazon-clone with the react project

Comment: The process isn't processing

Comment: Can you share your npm & node versions

Comment: Run `npm audit` for details.        
^C^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? y
PS D:\Amazon> npm --version
7.20.6
PS D:\Amazon> node --version
v14.17.5

Comment: What does "The process isn't processing" mean? Your question should contain a thorough description of the problem, and currently, it doesn't contain any problem description at all.

Comment: Have you previously installed create-react-app locally or globally?
using this command `npm install -g create-react-app`

Comment: @amnah i used once npx cerate-react-app my-app

Comment: and I am sorry I don't remember that whether I have ever used or not, installed create-react-app locally or globally?

Comment: This is a common bug. If you go here https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/
it says that  "if you've previously installed create-react-app globally via npm install -g create-react-app, we recommend you uninstall the package using npm uninstall -g create-react-app or yarn global remove create-react-app to ensure that npx always uses the latest version."

Comment: you can give this a try. Your node & npm versions meet requirements.

Comment: PS D:\Amazon> npm uninstall -g create-react-app

up to date, audited 1 package in 948ms

found 0 vulnerabilities

Comment: PS D:\Amazon> npx create-react-app amazon-clone2

Creating a new React app in D:\Amazon\amazon-clone2.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...


added 1919 packages, and audited 1920 packages in 2m

147 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

10 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: @JLRishe sorry but I mean I was creating an amazon clone by react I use npx create-react-app amazon-clone but then I got stuck ( I shared my terminal info above ) because further process isn't processing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60486006/unable-to-create-a-new-project-with-create-react-app?rq=1
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59188624/template-not-provided-using-create-react-app

Comment: @amnah still not working ??

Comment: Try creating another react app using this command ` init react-app my-app` and see if this works or not

Comment: still not working @amnah

Comment: PS D:\React> npm install -g create-react-app
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.

added 67 packages, and audited 68 packages in 9s

4 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

3 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix

Run `npm audit` for details.

Answer (score 0):

1. The official documents states  "if you've previously installed create-react-app globally via npm install -g create-react-app, we recommend you uninstall the package using npm uninstall -g create-react-app or yarn global remove create-react-app to ensure that npx always uses the latest version."
2. Once you've uninstalled create-react-app package. Clean npm cache using command `npm cache clean --force`
3. Try creating a fresh project
   `npx create-react-app project-app`

Comment: run this. `npm rm -g create-react-app` in cmd.
then run `npx create-react-app --info` and share the version it shows

Comment: PS C:\Users\HIMANSHU> npm rm -g create-react-app

up to date, audited 1 package in 786ms

found 0 vulnerabilities

Comment: PS C:\Users\HIMANSHU> npx create-react-app --info

Environment Info:

  current version of create-react-app: 4.0.3
  running from C:\Users\HIMANSHU\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\c67e74de0542c87c\node_modules\create-react-app

  System:
    OS: Windows 10 10.0.19041
    CPU: (2) x64 Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU G3240 @ 3.10GHz
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.1.0 - ~\node_modules\.bin\node.CMD
    Yarn: Not Found
    npm: 7.21.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 92.0.4515.131
    Edge: Spartan (44.19041.1.0), Chromium (86.0.622.51)
    Internet Explorer: 11.0.19041.1

Comment: npmPackages:
    react: Not Found
    react-dom: Not Found
    react-scripts: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    create-react-app: Not Found

Comment: And I want to use react in Local Disk D

Comment: I reset my pc now I can use react app thanks to everyone special thanks to @amnah