# Inline bash script in package.json on Windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, bash

I'm currently using this to git tag a commit in Linux via bash:

```
"tag": "VER=v$(node -p \"require('./package.json').version\") && git tag -a \"$VER\" -m \"$VER\"",
```

Does anyone know a way to make this both Linux and Windows friendly?

Comment: It doesn't answer the general question, but for this specific task note that `npm version` will create a tag by default when run in a git repo.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9153571/7665043).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set shell for npm run-scripts in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23243353/how-to-set-shell-for-npm-run-scripts-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Ok just found the easiest way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46006249/1137669

Set npm to use bash on Windows.

```
npm config set script-shell "C:\\Program Files\\git\\bin\\bash.exe"
```