# Docker stop all containers command in an NPM script?

Tags: docker, package.json, npm-scripts

When I run `docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)` to stop all Docker containers. **It works fine.** It stops all running containers.

But if I add to an NPM script, like:

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "docker:stop-all": "docker:stop-all": "docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)"
}
```

And I run: `npm run docker:stop-all`

I'm getting this error:

```
> docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)

unknown shorthand flag: 'a' in -a    

See 'docker stop --help'.
```

How can I execute that `stop-all` command by using an NPM script?

Comment: You can create a `stop-all.sh` script containing `docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)`, then call it by `docker:stop-all": "bash ./path/to/stop-all.sh"`.

Comment: Thanks. Is this the easier way to go? Will it work on Windows PowerShell? Or is it a Linux-specific solution?

Comment: It's *nix specific as it is, but if you're using the WSL it should be cross platform.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter I got this: `The command 'docker' could not be found in this WSL 2 distro. We recommend to activate the WSL integration in Docker Desktop settings.`

Comment: I don't use Windows myself, so I can't say for certain, but I would assume it would work if you install docker desktop and ensure the docker executable is in your PATH variable.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter it works on Git bash. But does not work on PowerShell.

Comment: Will research further. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just found out what was the problem.

When you call `npm run`, npm itself will run a shell to run those instructions.

And that shell should be able to understand the instructions.

If npm calls PowerShell (on Windows), for example, it will not understand `$(docker ps -a -q)` since it's a Bash specific instruction.

So you need to config npm so it will execute `bash` or `git-bash` instead of Windows `cmd` or `PowerShell`.

I found out how to set that config on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23243353/how-to-set-shell-for-npm-run-scripts-in-windows).

```
npm config set script-shell "C:\\Program Files\\git\\bin\\bash.exe"
```

You can list your npm configs to check that it worked:

```
npm config ls
```