# Ask users to input value for npm script

Tags: npm

I have an npm script, which is run like that:

```
npm run start:local -- -target.location https://192.1.1.1:8052/
```

The URL param is the local IP of a user.

What I would love to have is to ask users to input this value, because it's different for everybody.

Is it possible? Would be great to do it with vanila npm scripts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending command line arguments to npm script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580961/sending-command-line-arguments-to-npm-script)

Comment: Nope, it does not (or at least I can't find how it suggests to ask users for inputting params).

Comment: Your can call a bash script from your npm script that reads in a parameter from the user. There's lots of examples of interactive bash scripts out there.

Comment: However in node land I'd expect to have to run this as URL=localhost npm run start

Comment: What is the contents of the "scripts" property of your `package.json` file?

Comment: @MarkDolbyrev -  What is the intended UX for your requirement? Are the steps as follows (or something else)? **1)** User runs `npm run start:local` via CLI **2)** User is asked to enter local IP address and port number via CLI. **3)**  User types/enters e.g. `192.1.1.1:8052` via CLI **4)** An argument/parameter is formed to produce e.g. `-target.location https://192.1.1.1:8052/` _(based on  user input from step 3)_ **5)** The resultant argument is then appended to a command which is then invoked.....  Please clarify, and also provide details about the command(s) that should be invoked .

Comment: @RobC, your steps describe exactly what I need.

Comment: The whole approach is rather questionable, when the user has to lookup the IP. Besides the local loopback interface `127.0.0.1` suffices for a local install to test with (more complexity than required). Selecting one from available interfaces would rather be good UX, which properly supports laziness.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [readline](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) to get the ip value then use [exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_cal) to spawn this process. This is a pure JS solution, and OS agnostic.

Example:

###### package.json

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm run start:local -- -target.location",
    "prompt": "node prompt.js"
},
```

###### prompt.js

```js
const { spawn, execSync } = require('child_process');
const exec = commands => {
  execSync(commands, { stdio: 'inherit', shell: true });
};
const spawnProcess = commands => {
  spawn(commands, { stdio: 'inherit', shell: true });
};
   const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('What is your current ip? example: https://192.168.1.10:9009 ', (ip) => {
  console.log(`Starting server on: ${ip}`);
  exec(`npm run start -- ${ip}`);
  rl.close();
});
```

Answer (score 12):

Simply speaking, an `npm script` will run the desired command in your shell environment.

In a shell script, the arguments passed can be accessed using `$N` where N = Position of the argument.

Talking about your case, the command you want to run is
`npm run start:local -- -target.location USER_INPUT`
USER_INPUT needs to replaced with the argument that the user has passed. Assuming that the user will pass location as the first argument to the script, it can be accessed using `$1`.

I have created [this gist](https://gist.github.com/SNikhill/9e29d756909bba4dae058b7dfb0ed9e7) to demonstrate the same.

[image]

As you can clearly see, I have defined `start:local` to access the first argument and then, pass it to the `start` script which then echoes out the passed in argument.

[image]

**UPDATE:**
Here is the script for ASKING a value from a user in a prompt format.
[image]

Basically, first I am asking for user input then, storing the same in a variable and passing the variable as an argument to `npm start`

[image]

### References

- [Accessing Positional Arguments](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/use-command-line-arguments-in-bash-script#processing-the-input)
- [Asking User Input](https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-input.php)

Comment: As far as I understand the code doesn't ASK users to input some values. Am I missing smth?

Comment: I see. So, you want a prompt rather than passing the location as an argument, right?

Comment: The answer has been updated to include the "ASK" functionality.

Comment: It looks like your solution requires some bash scripts (does the "read location" command runs some sort of a bash script?). I would love to avoid it and use vanila npm (if possible).

Comment: Nope, it is not a bash script. It is a bash syntax to accept the input from the `stdin`. But, I believe your question was regarding the concern with windows user. In that case, I recommend running all the `npm scripts` in [a bash environment accessible using `git-bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23243353/how-to-set-shell-for-npm-run-scripts-in-windows).

Answer (score 4):

Example: If we want to run below three commands in **sequence** with **userinput**

```
git add .
git commit -m "With git commit message at run time"
git push
```

Add below command in your `package.json` file under the `scripts`

```
"gitPush": "git add . && echo 'Enter Commit Message' && read message && git commit -m \"$message\" && git push"
```

[image]

And run commands via `npm run gitPush`

[image]

**References:** [ask-users-to-input-value-for-npm-script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67224806/11754047)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to ask for users to input ther response you could do something like this.

```js
const readline = require("readline");

const reader = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
    error: process.stderr
});

const ask = (message, default_value = null) => new Promise(resolve => {
    reader.question(message, (response)=>{
        return resolve(response.length >= 1 ? response : default_value);
    });
});

(()=>{
    let ip = await ask(`Please enter your public ip: `);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the above answers are good, but if you just need a little bit of data from the user they seem like overkill. For simple user input you might try the following and avoid additional files or third party libraries.

```json
{
    "step1": "#!/usr/bin/env bash \n read -p \"What is your name? \" name \n npm run step2 $name",
    "step2": "echo Hello, $1",
}
```

Here is an example of how you might use it to start a http server on a user specified port:

```json
{
    "http1": "#!/usr/bin/env bash \n read -p \"What port do you want to use? \" port \n npm run http2 $port",
    "http2": "http-server . -p $1",
}
```

For a slightly more complex example you might use `npm-run-all`. For example this will have the user type a specific string before continuing.

```json
{
    "reset": "run-s --print-label reset:*",
    "reset:confirm": "#!/usr/bin/env bash \n set -e \n read -p \"Are you sure you want to reset everything? Type YES to continue : \" confirm \n if \n [ \"$confirm\" != \"YES\" ] ; then \n exit 1 \n fi",
    "reset:db": "..."
}
```