# npm Install error- node modules but no package-lock.json

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, nvm

I'm getting an error with my npm install and would love some help/advice.

```
ELIFECYCLE
ENOENT
spawn bash
yorkie@2.0.0 install `node bin/install.js`
spawn bash ENOENT
Failed at the yorkie@2.0.0 install script
This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

My node path is set in my environmental variables. My node version is 10.24.1 and npm version is 6.4.1
I am using nvm for windows to manage versions.
Whenever I run npm install I get this error, and node modules is created, but package-lock is not.
I have deleted node modules and ran npm cache clear with no success.

Any tips appreciated!

Comment: You know that Node v10 has been obsolete for quite a while now, right? It stopped receiving any sort of support in April of 2021 and has basically been a security vulnerability since (the current "emergency maintenance only" LTS is v14, with the current "normal" LTS being v16). Also, note that Node 10.24.1 [ships with](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/) npm 6.8.275.32 so the fact that your npm is _below_ the bundled version is a strong sign it's time to reinstall Node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it for me!

```
npm config delete script-shell
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46006249/15787997

Answer (score 0):

Try and run the following command.

```
npm install --registry=https://registry.npm.taobao.org
```

If that doesn't work, see the following Issues page on GitHub.

[yorkie@2.0.0 error](https://github.com/PanJiaChen/vue-element-admin/issues/2628)

**EDIT:** Just noticed, you should update your Node.js version. It is on `v10` and the current LTS version (at the time posted) is `v16`. This is just a suggestion, although it might solve your issue.

Comment: Nope... still getting the same error unfortunately

Comment: There is an Issues page on GitHub about this same issue at [this link](https://github.com/PanJiaChen/vue-element-admin/issues/2628).

Comment: Did you update Node.js to the LTS?