# Package.json script not working properly but the cli command specified in the script works fine when written

Tags: node.js, npm, environment-variables, command-line-interface

When I try to run this command in my git bash
`npm run prod` it doesn't work but if i wrote the command i specified `NODE_ENV=production nodemon server.js` it works fine
[image]

[image]

here is how it looks in the package.json file

```
    "dev": "nodemon server.js",
    "prod": "NODE_ENV=production nodemon server.js",
    "debug": "ndb server.js"
  },
```

Comment: Node is probably attempting to use `cmd.exe` to execute scripts. Try using something like [cross-env](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env) to set inline environment variables

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set environment variables from within package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112510/how-to-set-environment-variables-from-within-package-json)

Comment: @Phil i am writing the command in my git bash doesn't that mean it gets executed in the same terminal i am using?

Comment: `npm` starts a new shell to execute scripts IIRC and uses `cmd.exe` by default on Windows. See [How to set shell for npm run-scripts in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23243353/283366)

Comment: @Phil thanks a lot that actually fixed it when i changed the shell!!!