How to solve error when running npm start
I'm trying to run the quill editor.
I'm receiving error when trying to debug my node application using the npm start command under Windows.
Error:
'[[' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

This is a fragment of package.json

  "scripts": {
    "build": "./scripts/build production",
    "lint": "run-s lint:*",
    "lint:eslint": "eslint .",
    "lint:tsc": "tsc --noEmit --skipLibCheck",
    "start": "[[ -z \"$npm_package_config_ports_webpack\" ]] && webpack-dev-server || webpack-dev-server --port $npm_package_config_ports_webpack",
    "test": "run-s test:*",
    "test:unit": "vitest --config test/unit/vitest.config.ts",
    "test:fuzz": "vitest --config test/fuzz/vitest.config.ts",
    "test:e2e": "playwright test"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "quill",
    "editor",
    "rich text",
    "wysiwyg",
    "operational transformation",
    "ot",
    "framework"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "npm": ">=8.2.3"
  },
  "engineStrict": true
}



Edit:
I execute npm start use WSL and git/bash, but I recieved error:
> quill@2.0.2 start
> [[ -z "$npm_package_config_ports_webpack" ]] && webpack-dev-server || webpack-dev-server --port $npm_package_config_ports_webpack

'[[' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
  npx update-browserslist-db@latest
  Why you should do it regularly: https://github.com/browserslist/update-db#readme
[webpack-cli] RangeError [ERR_SOCKET_BAD_PORT]: options.port should be >= 0 and < 65536. Received type number (NaN).


[[ ]] is a feature of the bash so either run this under WSL or on a linux system or configure your npm shell to be something compatible to bash, like shown here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23243353/how-to-set-shell-for-npm-run-scripts-in-windows

This question is similar to: How to set shell for npm run-scripts in Windows. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I execute npm start use WSL and git/bash, but I recieved error:
'[[' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

"'[[' is not recognized as an internal or external command" clearly is an error message of the windows CMD ... So you are not executing the script under a bash-compatible shell  I'm not really familiar with WSL though
